# Outlook MailItem cache issue when saving in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, interop, exchange-server, mailitem

I have a small WinForms program that allows my users to create email blasts for our clients. The app has two options: one is an HTML editor to design the email (works great) and the second is to import .msg or .oft template. 
Once the email is complete it is moved to a shared outlook mailing folder for a nightly macro send job.

Pretty simple stuff!

The problem: Once the template is open in the application outlook seems cache that version. If the user decided to get out make a change in the template Outlook doesn't pick up the update.

Note: If the users clicks on the "Preview" button they received the correct UPDATED version in their inbox. But when they submit the MailItem it picks up the old version.

```
 Dim newItem  as Outlook.MailItem = gobjOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(fileEmailTemplate.FileName)
```

The send command works fine `newItem.Send()`

But when I move it to the shared folder it gets the original version from somewhere.

```
Dim addFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
addFldr = StoreFLDR.Folders.Add(gobjNamespace.CurrentUser.Name & ": " & DateTime.Now.ToString())
newItem.Save()                 
newItem.Move(addFldr )
```

I have tried forcing the GC and SaveAs to another location and reload the template, no luck.

Comment: I just found out that the .msg/.otf file contains the original message if I edit it with a text editor. and the .net code picks up the old (original) message instead of the new edited one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from releasing underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

You may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article helpful. Anyway, it would be great to see your full source code related to Outlook.

Comment: hi thanks for the link! good article! I do release all the objects as soon as I am done with them. I was testing a few things yesterday and found out that... While my application is closed (completely) i create a new .otf file and add a some text to it like "Hello, World!" save it and exit. i then reopen that file and change the text to "Hello, Hello!". When i open my application and use the .otf file the MailItem.Send command sends the updated version but when i move the file it moves the original "Hello, World!" text ... I have no idea where it gets it from! any help?

Comment: I edit the message using Outlook 2010. and load it with CreateItemFromTemplate

Comment: You need to publish all the code if you want to get any suggestion or solution.